# Akka HTTP client akka-http akka-http-jackson

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I am trying to make an actor calls a simple GET on rest service. For that I'm using `akka-http-experimental_2.11`, and `akka-http-jackson-experimental_2.11`. Try as I might I couldn't find a comprehensible **java** example. The call is to be made async and the response mapped to a POJO.

Can you please help? I'm lost between `Sink`s, `Flow`s and `CompletionStage<HttpResponse>`s.

Thank you **java** hAkkers :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a look at the docs?

Relevant links:

- The HTTP client -
  http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/java/http/client-side/request-level.html#request-level-api-java
- Akka Streams, which it is probably a good idea to at least have a basic understanding of to use Akka HTTP -
  http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/java/stream/index.html